# SDK Project DependentUpon needed?

Tags: c#

When converting a csproj file to the new SDK project, **EnableDefaultItems** is true and all resources, cs files etc are automatically included. So basically the project file is almost empty which is good.

Now the problem is, that Visual Studio sees no connection between the .resx file and the Resources.designer.cs file and doesn't update it automatically.

To solve this, I need to add this DependsUpon statement

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Update="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
    <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
    <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
    <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Update="Properties\Resources.resx">
    <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
    <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
  </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

This is also inserted automatically when using the UI to create the resources. Is there a property or other way so I don't have to define this for all my resources?

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```xml
<Compile Update="**\*.Designer.cs">
  <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
  <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
  <DependentUpon>$([System.String]::Copy("%(Filename)").Replace(".Designer", "")).resx</DependentUpon>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

This will make all `*.Designer.cs` files in your project show as a subitem under the `*.resx` file in the same folder.